# Error with custom density function definition for mle2 formula call

Tags: r, poisson, mle

I want to define my own density function to be used in the formula call to `mle2` from `R`'s `bbmle` package. The parameters of the model are estimated but I cannot apply functions like `residuals` or `predict` on the returned `mle2` object.

This is an example in which I define a function for a simple Poisson model.

```
library(bbmle)

set.seed(1)
hpoisson <- rpois(1000, 10)

myf <- function(x, lambda, log = FALSE) {
  pmf <- (lambda^x)*exp(-lambda)/factorial(x)
  if (log)
    log(pmf)
  else
    pmf
}

myfit <- mle2(hpoisson ~ myf(lambda), start = list(lambda=9), data=data.frame(hpoisson))
residuals(myfit)
```

In `myfit`, the lambda is estimated correctly but when I call residuals on `myfit`, I get an error which says:

```
Error in myf(9.77598906811668) : 
  argument "lambda" is missing, with no default
```

On the other hand, if I simply fit the model as follows using `R`'s built-in `dpois` function, the residuals are computed:

```
myfit <- mle2(hpoisson ~ dpois(lambda), start = list(lambda=9), data=data.frame(hpoisson))
    residuals(myfit)
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong in the function definition of `myf`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clearly explained in the documents, but there are a few prerequisites for using custom density functions:

- the function's name **must start with `d`**, must have first argument `x`, and must have a named argument `log`. (*The `log` argument has to do something sensible*: in particular, `mle2` will call the function with `log=TRUE`, and the function had better return the log-likelihood!)  In general, although it's not required, it's more numerically sensible to compute the log-likelihood directly and then exponentiate if `log=FALSE`, rather than computing the likelihood and logging it if `log=TRUE` (there are cases, such as zero-inflated models, where this isn't really feasible). For example, compare my `dmyf()` definition with the `myf()` definition in the OP's code ...
- in order to use additional methods such as `predict` you have to define an additional function whose name starts with `s`; it returns a list of moments, summary statistics, etc. for a specified parameter -- see example below, which is copied from `bbmle::spois`.

```
library("bbmle")
set.seed(1)
hpoisson <- rpois(1000, 10)

dmyf <- function(x, lambda, log = FALSE) {
    logpmf <- x*log(lambda)-lambda-lfactorial(x)
    if (log) return(logpmf)  else return(exp(logpmf))
}
smyf <- function(lambda) {
    list(title = "modified Poisson",
         lambda = lambda, mean = lambda,
         median = qpois(0.5, lambda),
         mode = NA, variance = lambda, sd = sqrt(lambda))
}
myfit <- mle2(hpoisson ~ dmyf(lambda),
              start = list(lambda=9), data=data.frame(hpoisson))
residuals(myfit)
```

Comment: Dear Ben, my goal is to define a non-homogeneous Poisson process  where the lambda in dmyf is a function of covariates. Again, I have tried that and the coefficients of the covariates are estimated correctly. But I was wondering if in this case the moments I specify in smyf will make any sense and if I can correctly predict the outcome of the process and produce some diagnostics on it. Do you have any suggestions where I can find more info? I've already tried NHPoisson which produces great plots but I'm not sure I can tailor it to my needs. So I was wondering if this can be done with bbmle.

Comment: Well, if you want to calculate residuals, then you need to define *some* predicted value so that you can compare the predicted and observed values ...

Comment: I tried to use these tips to make my own dbetabinom- but I got an error.  See new "Answer" below because I could not do fancier formatting in comments.  Help me @BenBolker, you're my only hope...

Comment: @BenBolker I still have an issue with my custom function. Can you see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443537/mle2-from-package-bbmle-gives-non-sensical-answers-with-custom-function ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but more help needed on this:

I used this to try to make a "custom" beta-binomial function to mimic the one in the first bit of the bbmle vignette.

```
set.seed(1001)
x1 <- rbetabinom(n=1000, prob=0.1, size=50, theta=10)
dmybetabinom <- function(x, N, theta, p, log=FALSE) {
    (choose(N,x)*beta(N-x+theta*(1-p),x+theta*p))/beta(theta*(1-p),theta*p)
}
```

The function works like dbetabinom:

`dbetabinom(0:9,size=9,theta=4, prob=0.5)
 [1] 0.04545455 0.08181818 0.10909091 0.12727273 0.13636364 0.13636364 0.12727273 0.10909091
 [9] 0.08181818 0.04545455
dmybetabinom(0:9,N=9,theta=4, p=0.5)
 [1] 0.04545455 0.08181818 0.10909091 0.12727273 0.13636364 0.13636364 0.12727273 0.10909091
 [9] 0.08181818 0.04545455`

But when I try to use the mle2 function on it, I am met with this error:

```
m0fa <- mle2(x1~dmybetabinom( N=50, theta, p), start=list(p=0.2, theta=9), data=data.frame(x1) )`

Error in optim(par = c(0.2, 9), fn = function (p)  :   non-finite finite-difference value [1] `
```

Comment: You could make this a new question ...  I believe your problem is that you *must* provide a `log=TRUE` option, because that's what `mle2` is going to ask for.   I will amplify this in my answer.